# Xml path send via post and insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Actually i have one server side xml path.I am post path throw form  action and getting that xml path information and insert into MySQL. Please give me some suggestions about that.

Comment: Start [here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Where is problem in sending data, getting xml path or insert into database ?